# Logout facebook issues

Tags: android, facebook

I can already log-in and out from facebook in my application (Android).

But what I want to do is when I logout from facebook,

I want it to return to the login page.  Any idea?... Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

May need to call Facebook APIs: Auth.expireSession and Auth.revokeAuthorization

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the session is active, if it's not, just call the authorize method again - this will show the login page.

Comment: Now I can login again but still have to pressed button. Are there anyway to make it pop right up after logout? thanks